# Advanced Developer Features Could not be Located (Windows Developer Mode)

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I am getting the error "advanced developer features could not be located in windows update" when trying to enable developer mode in Windows 10.  I am running the latest creators update of Windows (Version 1703 Build 15063.483).

I am also getting System.DllNotFoundException errors in the xaml designer along the lines of

```
Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpInterop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.Views.PresentSiteWrapper.NativeMethods.CreatePresentSite(IntPtr& handlePresentSite)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.Views.PresentSiteWrapper..ctor()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.Views.UwpImageHost.EnsureWindowsUIXamlInitialized()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.WindowsUIXamlDomainManager.CreateDomainCore()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.WindowsUIXamlDomainManager.CreateDomainInitial()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpDesigner.UwpPlatformCreator.CreatePlatformInternal(IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver referenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.PlatformCreatorBase.CreatePlatform(IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver referenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Documents.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetProjectContext(IHostProject project, IPlatform platform, Boolean create)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Documents.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetSourceItemContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<MarshalInWithCancellation>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
```

I'm not sure if these 2 errors are related or not.  I've been looking around for over a day now and can't find a resolution for either problem.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to say I am running Visual Studio 2017 Professional